# VSCode Formatter causing error on my django project

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, formatter

Currently I am working on my Django project with VSCode, and in my `html` files, I select the Django-Html as my language mode. I have multiple blocks {%__%} in my html files.
for example:

```
{% block navbar %} {% endblock navbar %} {% block footer %} {% endblock footer %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE6fz.png)

The problem is, when I save the file, VSCode will auto format my html and move my _%} to next line which will make the endblock cannot recognize it properly

After saving:

```
{% block navbar %} {% endblock navbar %} {% block 

footer %} {% endblock footer %}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agxYz.png)

So is there anyone who has experienced this and knows how to fix it?

Comment: it didn't recognized ? can u show the output html?

Comment: yeah, it says : Invalid block tag on line 2: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tage?

Comment: well then , this is not a html syntax page. its called jinja template. You can install that extension & it will detect the jinja formatting automatically

Comment: i just download the extension and tired to use jinja as my language mode but it still misplace my blocks.

Answer (score 2):

**Disable code formatting for that workspace**

1. Go to extension tab search for prettier You notice a small arrow with disable button click on it
2. And select  Disable(Workspace).
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing the language mode to just plain `HTML` and try it, or update the extension for `Django_HTML`, one other suggestion I'd like to give is to try using an extension called prettier I personally use it for formatting, you should give it a try.

Comment: emm, I've tried to change the language mode before i save but it still happened. And i am using prettier as well. Appreciate for your help anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** You can try using  prettier-ignore for the line that you wish not to be formatted. Ensure prettier ignore is a html comment

e.g

`<!-- prettier-ignore -->`

`{% block navbar %}{% endblock navbar %} {% block footer %} {% endblock footer %}`

this will ignore the line below the prettier-ignore when formatting and the rest of the code will not be affected.

To effect this on vs code, place the cursor on the prettier-ignore line and press ctrl + /

**Option 2:**
You can use jinja2 templating engine instead of the default django templating engine.

When using jinja2, even if the code is formatted as you posted, your code will still work okay.

For a step by step guide on how to add jinja to your django project, see [Adding jinja2 templating engine to django step by step](https://azwdjango.blogspot.com/2023/08/how-to-add-jinja2-templating-in-django.html)